# "primary-expression before '.' token error" in g++

Tags: c++, g++

I have this C++ code to generate "primary-expression before '.' token' error with g++ compiler. It compiles OK with cl (MSVC) compiler.

```
template<typename T>
class A : public std::auto_ptr<T>
{
    typedef std::auto_ptr<T> Super;
public:
    A() : Super() { }
    A(T* t) : Super(t) { }
    A(AP<T>& o) : Super(o) { }
    operator bool() { return !!Super.get(); } <--- error!
};
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: By the way, that `!!` construct isn't necessary when converting to `bool`; you only need it in old-school C if you're storing booleans as `int`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Super` is a type.  If you want to call the base class function, you can do so via `this`:

```
this->get();
```

Note that `this->` is only required here because `get()` is a member function of a dependent base class; that is, a base class that is dependent upon the template parameter `T`.  For more information, consult the Parashift C++ FAQ article, ["Why am I getting errors when my template-derived-class uses a member it inherits from its template-base-class?"](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/templates.html#faq-35.19)

Comment: @prosseek: either is fine. I prefer `this->get()` since it doesn't depend on any type names.

Comment: Note that if `get()` were virtual, `this->get()` and `Super::get()` would mean two different things.